# How to customise a Mapbox route's style?

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox

My function successfully renders a route from origin to destination:

```
private fun renderRouteToDestination(){
    val origin = Point.fromLngLat(initialLocation!!.longitude, initialLocation!!.latitude)
    val destination = Point.fromLngLat(143.152001, -37.260811)
    val navRoute = NavigationRoute.builder(context)
        .accessToken(getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token))
        .origin(origin)
        .profile(DirectionsCriteria.PROFILE_WALKING)
        .destination(destination)
        .build()
    navRoute.getRoute(object : Callback<DirectionsResponse> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<DirectionsResponse>, t: Throwable) {}

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<DirectionsResponse>, response: Response<DirectionsResponse>) {
                val routeResponse = response ?: return
                val body = routeResponse.body() ?: return
                if (body.routes().count() == 0){
                    Log.d(TAG, "There were no routes")
                    return
                }
                if (navigationMapRoute != null) navigationMapRoute?.updateRouteVisibilityTo(false)
                navigationMapRoute = NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView!!, mapbox)
                val directionsRoute = body.routes().first()
                navigationMapRoute?.addRoute(directionsRoute)
                Log.d(TAG, "Successful got route to destination")
            }
        })
}
```

[image]

However I would like to customise the route in 2 ways:

1. Change the color of the route
2. Make the route dotted instead of solid

How can I achieve these styles?

Answer (score 1):

The the Android Nav SDK documentation goes into specific detail about how to modify the style defaults of the route line here: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/overview/map-styling/#style-the-map-route

The bottom line is that you can override these defaults by providing an alternative style when you initialize your `NavigationMapRoute`

———

⚠️ disclaimer: I currently work at Mapbox ⚠️